# A different kind of treasure

Tags: riddle, word

I am a box without hinges, key, or lid;
Yet golden treasure inside is hid.

What am I?

Credit to J.R.R. Tolkien (from The Hobbit)

Comment: If you know where Tolkein got it from, you should credit that source. Otherwise credit Tolkein.

Comment: Who is Tolkein?

Comment: JRR Tolkein wrote the book The Hobbit, in which this riddle appears: https://genius.com/J-r-r-tolkien-the-hobbit-chapter-5-riddles-in-the-dark-annotated

Comment: Uh I don't know him so I'll just credit him

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you an

> Egg

So,

> It is not a box, yet it has a wonderful golden yolk.